# Renaming Multiple Printers "Rename-Printer"

Tags: powershell, csv, printing

Having trouble with trying to import a .csv or .txt with multiple printer names (shown below). Running this locally on a server to change printer names in a list.

```
oldName,newName
printer1,printer2
```

From what VSCode is telling me is that these lines are erroring out for some reason and I can not figure it out for the life of me. Commented out some lines for testing.

```
Rename-Printer -Name $OldName -NewName $NewName
#Rename-Printer -InputObject $Computer -NewName $Computers.newName -Verbose
```

Code below (was trying .txt for a bit) :

```
#$Computers = import-csv .\printers.csv -Header 'oldName', 'newName'
$Computers = Import-Csv .\printers.txt -Header 'oldName', 'newName'
foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
    $OldName = $($Computer.oldName)
    $NewName = $($Computer.newName)
    Rename-Printer -Name $OldName -NewName $NewName
    #Rename-Printer -InputObject $Computer -NewName $Computers.newName -Verbose
}

Get-Printer | select Name,Comment,ShareName,PortName | Export-Csv C:\Users\$username$\Desktop\exportPrinters.csv -NoTypeInformation
Pause
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the two $Vars have what you expect them to have? look for things like leading or trailing spaces ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have not actually. I didn't even think about that. How would one go about that? I see something about going into Excel and checking "Text to Columns"

Comment: The csv you're showing us already has headers, in which case, `-Header` should not be needed. Also, having the details on the error message would help us understand what could be wrong.

Comment: the way i usually check for "extra stuff" is to either send them to `Format-Hex` or do a check on the values. if `'Monday'`  does not equal `'Monday'.Trim()` ... then you know there is a glitch. [*grin*]

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon tried taking it out and got this error when running :/ 
Import-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Char' required by parameter 'Delimiter'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\Change Printers\Change Printer Name.ps1:15 char:40
+ $Computers = Import-Csv .\printers.txt 'oldName','newName'
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon also here is the other error I'm getting. I'm getting this twice. 1 for both Variables I think. 
Rename-Printer : The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.
At C:\Users\elliro\Desktop\Change Printers\Change Printer Name.ps1:19 char:5
+     Rename-Printer -Name $OldName -NewName $NewName
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Rename-Printer], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Rename-Printer

Answer (score -2):

You don't need that much code for such a simple task

```
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\test.csv' | %{Rename-Printer -Name $_.oldName.Trim() -NewName $_.newName.Trim() -ErrorAction Continue}
Get-Printer | select Name,Comment,ShareName,PortName | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\exportPrinters.csv -NoTypeInformation
Pause
```

Issues were: "Import-csv" will automatically pick up headers, and your "Export-Csv" had an extra $ in it. If you're concerned about whitespace, adding .Trim() to a string object will trim any whitespace from the ends.

Comment: The bigger issue is that you’ve simply provided another solution but no insight as to what OP was doing wrong. He’s wanting to learn why his solution is not working - not given a new solution.

Comment: Tried this and got this error.

Rename-Printer : The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' 
characters.
At C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\Change Printers\Change Printer Name.ps1:27 char:31
+ ... ers.csv | %{Rename-Printer -Name $_.oldName.Trim() -NewName $_.newNam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Rename-Printer], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Rename-Printer

Comment: Can you post up your printers.csv to pastebin? Sounds like hte issue is how the names are defined in your list.